# Why Composer's package dependencies are not being installed?

Tags: json, dependencies, composer-php

I've got the following `composer.json` file:

```
{
  "require": {
    "local/my_package": "dev-master"
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "packagist.org": false
    },
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "my_package/"
    }
  ]
}
```

which requires my local package which defines the following `my_package/composer.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "local/my_package",
  "require-dev": {
    "symfony/console": "*"
  }
}
```

<sup>Note: The `my_package` folder is under Git repository with the default `master` branch.</sup>

<sup>Note: To create new repo, run: `git init && git add -A && git commit -am'Files'`.</sup>

When I run: `composer install -vvv`, the `local/my_package` package is installed correctly, but nothing else. I would expect that dependencies defined in `symfony/console` should be installed as well.

> `Executing command (my_package/): git log -n1 --pretty=%H`
>
> `- Installing local/my_package (dev-master)`

How should I correct my `composer.json` file, so the package's dependencies can be installed automatically?

Comment: Silly question: if you disable installing from packagist.org, from which source should `symfony/console` get installed?

Comment: @NicoHaase Good catch, but it seemed it worked anyway, even you disable Packagist.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the [`require-dev`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#require-dev) keyword in the package's `composer.json` file should be **changed to [`require`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#require)**.

The `require-dev` property is only required for developing the package ([root package](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#root-package)).